# Program needs local user on server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012

I have windows server 2012 setup to use remote desktop. I have a program that I wanted to run in this environment. When I try to start the program it says it can not find a local user. Is there anyway of setting up a local user, when the server is a domain server?

To summarize how do I setup a local user when I have the active domain server installed?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that your server is an Active Directory domain controller (DC), then you cannot do what you are describing.

What would be the local groups on the DCs are actually in the domain. For example, if you look in the Builtin container in AD, you'll see an Administrators group. That is the group of accounts with administrator rights to the DCs. Each DC does not have its own Administrators group, as would be the case with member servers. The same goes for the other groups that you would otherwise see on a member or standalone server.

Some software specifically says you cannot install it on a DC, and this is probably the reason a decent percentage of the time.